# Perform a button click when activity opens

Tags: android

I have an activity which has a button which opens up a custom `AlertDialog` (in which user can enter some data) when pressed. I now have a requirement to open this activity with the alert dialog open initially.

I know that I can perform a click on the button programmatically by calling `button.performClick();`. My question is, when should I call this? Is it safe to call it in `onCreate()`?

Comment: sure. You can can call it there or show the dialog directly from on create. Make sure you do it after setting your view.

Comment: It would be better init view in `onCreate`, and perform click in `onResume`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can call it in `onCreate()` , if you want to call it only once,
but if want call that again you leave and come back to `Activity` it will be better to add in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call it in `onCreate()`, but if you set the AlertDialog as a login, I think it will be in `onStart()`. Because when you go to desktop, then if you want to get back, you should login again, right? And you can read the detailed information in [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).